# Save user info in one or multiple documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently overthinking something that should be trivial.
I need to save user info that is composed of different sections like settings, weather, profile.

Should I be saving each in a different document or everything under one document?

For me it kind of seems ambiguous (since these docs wont be queried) and I am scared I am missing or not considering something.

Comment: "Should I be saving each in a different document or everything under one document?" => Your question is way too broad for SO and we don't have enough contextual elements to answer in a sensible way... In particular: size and structure of the sections, are they going to be accessed separately, with different access rights?, etc..., etc...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Well it's personal user info. I said it is not going to be queried nor are there different access rights. Also the size of the documents are not big.

Answer (score 0):

There is no singular right way to model data in Firestore, nor in most other NoSQL databases. It all depends on the use-cases of your app, and you likely don't know all of those yet. So I find it best to just pick an approach, and see how far it gets you.

If you want to train yourself to get better at this, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video), which cover many scenarios of data modeling in Firestore (always in the context of a specific set of use-cases).